# How to get value type from string using nlohmann json?

Tags: c++, json

string I get

```
{
    "players": [
        {
            "SteamId": "765611974898245625",
            "CommunityBanned": false,
            "VACBanned": true,
            "NumberOfVACBans": 1,
            "DaysSinceLastBan": 1011,
            "NumberOfGameBans": 1,
            "EconomyBan": "none"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get from it

```
bool VACBanned = true;
int NumberOfVACBans = 1;
```

and so on

I use nlohmann json

```
using json = nlohmann::json;
auto j3 = json::parse(respone.c_str());

if (j3.is_boolean()) // crashing without this check
    g_Player[index].bVACBanned = j3.at("VACBanned").get<bool>();
```

for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: If you don't mind, I removed `visual c++` tag and added general `c++` and `json`.

Comment: Wouldn't `j3.is_boolean()` be false since `j3` should be an object containing an array called `players`?

Comment: @Kevin - certainly; that is why that faulty statement was bypassed and didn't crash :)

Comment: Which player do you want to get information for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used that parser before, just read its `readme.md`. It appears that both of these methods work:

```
bool b1 = j3.at("players")[0].at("VACBanned");
bool b2 = j3["players"][0]["CommunityBanned"];
```

Your JSON has one root node `players` that is an array; its first element is accessible by `[0]`; from that point you can access all parsed elements.

Add error checking per your tolerance level :)

P.S. This is just a syntax demo; I assume that OP can get the size of parsed array and iterate through it to get details on each player.

Also, to answer your *"for some reason it doesn't work*":

```
g_Player[index].bVACBanned = j3.at("VACBanned").get<bool>();
```

`j3` doesn't have an element `"VACBanned"`, so `at("VACBanned")` likely returns `nullptr` that you dereferenced.